# Where to get SQL CE 4.0 template for Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-ce

Where can I download a standalone installer for SQL CE 4.0 SDK / template to be used within Visual Studio 2010 > Project > Add Item?

I tried http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17876 but it appears to be the runtime only.

I have also downloaded VS 2010 SP1 from http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=23691 still no go. The about dialog version says SP1Rel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my blog post here for a direct link to the VS 2010 SP1 Tools for SQLCE 4.0 - http://erikej.blogspot.com/2011/01/sql-server-compact-40-released.html - keep in mind that the tooling is only avilable for Web project types.

Comment: maybe the web project limitation explains why I could not find it. why have this "feature"?

Comment: Because not all 3.5 SP2 features are available in 4.0 - see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2011/03/15/sql-server-compact-4-0-tooling-support-in-visual-studio-2010-sp1-and-visual-web-developer-express-2010-sp1.aspx